# Handle login form in header using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

For all of my "public" facing pages/routes I am using a controller I created called `Public_controller` which extends `CI_Controller`. Currently, `Public_controller` is an empty file with only the constructor function.

In my routes, I have defined `Application_controller` as my default controller. It's where routes like `mysite.com/about-us` point to:

**PHP**

```
class Application_controller extends Public_Controller {

public function about() {
        $data['page_title'] = 'About';
        $data['page_description'] = '';
        $data['page_keywords'] = '';
        $data['main_content'] = 'public/about';

        $this->load->view('public/templates/default', $data);
    }
}
```

I have a login form in the header of every public-facing page. I am familiar with how to handle/process the form(s) in CI. What I am struggling with is how to check for that globally rather than a one-off page.

For example, normally I would do this if my form was in the `<body>` of my page:

**PHP**

```
$this->load->library('form_validation');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'trim|required|xss_clean');

if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $data['main_content'] = 'public/forms/my_form';
    } else {
        // Handle the form.
    }
}

$this->load->view('public/templates/default', $data);
```

Everything is fine. I obviously can't have that type of syntax on every single controller method. A user could log in on any page - so I need to be able to listen/handle the form if they are logging in. Otherwise, I need to show the page that the user has requested.

Maybe I need another controller that extends `Public_controller`?

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: Its hard to understand what you want.Do you want all controllers can view by only logged user?

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood your issue correctly, you want your users to be able to log in from any page of your application.

There are multiple ways to do that, here is two :

### I/ Ajax solution

1/ Create a controller in charge of Ajax calls and write your login function there

**Ajax.php**

```
class Ajax extends CI_Controller 
{
    $email          = $this->input->post("mail_login"); 
    $password       = $this->input->post("pass_login");

    $user = $this->somemodel->get_user_by_mail_and_pass($email, $password);

    if($user)
    {
        //stuff if success
    }
    else
    {
        //Stuff if failed
    }
}
```

2/ Create a js file which will be loaded everywhere.

**myjsfile.js**
(I suppose you're using jQuery)

```
$("#theform").on("submit", function(event)
{
    event.preventDefault();
    var post_array =
    {
        "mail_login"    : $("#txt_mail_login").val(),
        "pass_login"    : $("#txt_pass_login").val()
    }

    $.ajaxSetup({async:false});
    $.post(baseUrl + "/Ajax/ajax_login", post_array,
        function(data)
        {
            //Stuff here (redirect, change form into user info....)
        });
)};
```

Voila !

---

### II/ "Classic" form submit

**In your header, where the login form is**

```
<form method="post" action="<?= site_url("My_controller/my_login_function/" . $_ci_view); ?>">
```

Here, We suppose that you have a function named my_login_function which is in charge of the logging. That function is located in a controller, here, my_controller (awful name :) ).

$_ci_view is a var that contains the name of the current view. We will use it to redirect the user where he was before the form submit.

For example, if your user has load the view home you'll get something like this in your form :

```
<form method="post" action="http://www.example.com/My_controller/my_login_function/home">
```

**My_controller.php**

```
class My_Controller extends CI_Controller
{
    public function user_login($view_name)
    {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'trim|required|xss_clean');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) 
        {
            //Your stuff here

            $this->load->view($view_name);
        } 
        else 
        {
            //Your stuff here

            $this->load->view($view_name);
        }


        $this->load->view('public/templates/default', $data);

    }
}
```

We can imagine that in case of success, you set a session with your user's data. And then, in your header, build a condition that shows or not the login form if the session is set.

Comment: I wish I could have given more details but my english skills are very limited ;)

Comment: You are correct - I would like the user to be able to log in on any page. Do you think passing login (un/pw) info to backed via ajax call is "secure" enough?

Comment: It is not less secure than a normal submit. Of course, you will have to take precautions on your server side to prevent any unwanted behavior.

Comment: Absolutely will. I will give this a try and see what I come up with. I appreciate your time & will update the thread with what I come up with for future benefit.